# how to get inputs from an email address?

Tags: html, survey

I made a website for a free summer camp program (nothing fancy im barely 20 and only know python and C++ so i used weebly). I made an online form asking for info such as campers t-shirt size and name, and when the user fills that out, weebly sends me an email containing all of their answers.

The issue is, that will require BARE MINIMUM, for me to manually type hundreds of answers into some C++ program that could sort these people and put them in the right age groups. My question is, is there any way to get the contents of my email, or set up an email that automatically puts everything it receives into a database?

Im still inexperienced so if someone knows of a BETTER way to do this or something I am all ears. This is non-profit so really just trying to save time and manpower, i have a little budget for something such as a hosting fees or anything like that, but solutions like learning SQL arent really workable. I have looked at many services online but things such as sign up genius don't support this kind of camp style (you can choose multiple camps from a pool and when a pool reaches 50 we cannot accept more in that pool) weebly supports html embedding if that helps.

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: "is there any way to get the contents of my email" — Start by looking for a library for whatever protocol you are using to read messages from your mail box.

Comment: "or set up an email that automatically puts everything it receives into a database" — That depends on your mail service. I'd write a procmail script. I doubt you are using a mail service that supports that.